# Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation in Aqua Data Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, settings

I have a problem when data is null and the warning has appear when the result is display.
How to solve this problem?. How to change the null data to 0 when no data in the table?.

This is my code:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.username             AS assigner_officer,
                d.description          AS ticketcategory,
                (SELECT Count(closed)
                 FROM   ticket
                 WHERE  assigned_to = c.user_id
                        AND closed IS NOT NULL
                 GROUP  BY assigned_to)closedcases,
                (SELECT Count(closed)
                 FROM   ticket
                 WHERE  assigned_to = c.user_id
                        AND closed IS NULL
                 GROUP  BY assigned_to)opencases
FROM   ticket a
       JOIN ticketlog b
         ON a.ticketid = b.ticketid
       JOIN access c
         ON a.assigned_to = c.user_id
       JOIN ticket_category d
         ON a.cat_code = d.id
       JOIN lookup_department e
         ON a.department_code = e.code
```

The result appear like this:-

```
 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
          <--- 
 assigner_officer     ticketcategory     closedcases     opencases    
 -------------------  -----------------  --------------  ------------ 
 abdulhafiz           Enquiry            (null)          0            
 affan                Enquiry            12              (null)       
 amirul               Enquiry            1               (null)       
 azrul_fahmi          Enquiry            45              0            
 Azwani               Enquiry            (null)          0            
 chai                 Enquiry            4               (null)       
 dalinawati           Enquiry            1               0            
 Emmy                 Complaints         (null)          0            
 Fadhlia              Enquiry            38              0            
 fairulhalif          Others             1               (null)       
 farikh               Enquiry            (null)          0            
 ismailh              Enquiry            28              0            
 izzahanna            Enquiry            (null)          0            
 Kamsuzilawati        Enquiry            1               (null)
```

Comment: `Count(closed) ... WHERE ... closed IS NULL` doesn't make any sense as `COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719436/getting-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation)

Comment: I'm getting the same warning. I don't mind the warning in and of itself, but, I need the stored procedure to be run by the SQL Agent, and when I do that, the warning causes the Agent job to fail.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MartinSmith https://stackoverflow.com/q/17468242/357313

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You would mostly be using `COUNT` to summarize over a UID.  Therefore

`COUNT([uid])` will produce the warning:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

whilst being used with a left join, where the counted object does not exist.

Using `COUNT(*)` in this case would also render incorrect results, as you would then be counting the total number of results (ie parents) that exist.

Using `COUNT([uid])` IS a valid way of counting, and the warning is nothing more than a warning.  However if you are concerned, and you want to get a true count of uids in this case then you could use:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [uid] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [new_count]
```

This would not add a lot of overheads to your query.
(tested mssql 2008)

Comment: I so searched and tried without success but using NULLIF conjunction with ISNULL saved me, You can try combination of these two for example: ISNULL(NULLIF([fieldValue], 0), 1)

Comment: Wouldn't the solution specifically for the "opencases" column be simpler as just "select count(1)..." (or "count" of any other literal)? The Where clause already specifies "and closed is NULL" so no need for summing a case statement in this instance. Also, I've heard (aeons ago) that "count(*)" is not as efficient as counting a single column or literal but not sure if that is still the case.

Comment: Instead of `count([uid])`, would it work to use `count(1)`?

Comment: You sir @Mat Traherne saved me :) I got this trying to connect data in an Excel file, already had a ISNULL(x,y) but that didn't work, however "SUM(CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE X END) AS Z" worked great! Thanks!

Comment: I used this "SUM(" solution because I have a loop to load remote data 1000 rows at a time, and the warning actually generated a 6 GB tmp file on my C drive and shut it down.  Of course, this is poor space management on my part, but just interesting.  It also can slow that query window way down.

Answer (score 32):

One way to solve this problem is by turning the warnings off.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
GO
```

Comment: From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx), this does not only change warnings about null in aggregates, but also modify the handling of divide by zero and overflow errors. This causes this solution to be a "no go" for me.

Comment: Why do you regard it as a problem anyway? [it is just informational](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18719852/73226)

Comment: @Mukus - No it doesn't. It prints out a message at Severity level 10. Anything 10 or lower is informational not regarded as an error. `SELECT SUM(X) FROM (VALUES ( 1 + NULL)) V(X);SELECT 'This is executed fine';`

Comment: When I turn off ANSI warnings, I get the following error, making this a non-solution for me. "Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query."

Comment: @RichieACC Yeah, because this is not an answer, and disabling the extremely desirable ANSI warnings as a lazy way of avoiding one informational message will cause breakage in many other, distinctly non-informational things.

Comment: I get this error when I try run query after this: SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: The solution to your car warning lights being on is to just unplug the dash. This is probably the worst answer I've ever seen on stackoverflow.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato, my coolant sensor itself went bad, and without spending lots of money replacing it, unplugging it was the best answer.
I have a valid case for wanting this particular warning message to shut up (i.e. just the coolant sensor), but definitely turning all ANSI warnings off is a very bad idea (i.e. unplugging the entire dashboard).

Comment: Yes to be clear when I said "Just unplug the dash" I meant literally to unplug the entire dash, not specifically the blinkenlights which are lighting.

Comment: While I agree with some of the comments above, about this being dangerous to disable, it still helped me enormously in debugging a large, badly written procedure with dozens of "group by" statements.  I was able to work out exactly which statement was causing the problem very quickly. (I used a binary search approach, setting the warnings off half way down the procedure, then running it and seeing which part of the procedure was causing the error. I then repeated this several times and found the exact problem. I AGREE THOUGH - you should not do it in a production environment.

Answer (score 17):

Use `ISNULL(field, 0)` It can also be used with aggregates:

```
ISNULL(count(field), 0)
```

However, you might consider changing `count(field) to count(*)`

Edit:

try:

```
closedcases = ISNULL(
   (select count(closed) from ticket       
    where assigned_to = c.user_id and closed is not null       
    group by assigned_to), 0), 

opencases = ISNULL(
    (select count(closed) from ticket 
     where assigned_to = c.user_id and closed is null 
     group by assigned_to), 0),
```

Comment: i have try but the (null) still exist in row. How to change this value to 0 when data is null?

Comment: thank you but the not null value also got the same problem when the null is appear. how to change the value to 0?.

Comment: FYI: `ISNULL(count(field), 0)` did not work for me in MSSQL 2008 R2.  The issue was because I was trying to count a field in a left outer joined table to get the number of records in the joined table related to the main table.  I ended up having to make a sub query which inner joined the two tables to get the count per ID in the main table.  The sub query was left outer joined to the main table on the ID.  The sub query's count was then wrapped in an ISNULL to get the 0 I wanted (without the warning message).

Comment: Chris, it should be COUNT(ISNULL(Field, 0)) not the other way around. Querying the current format, all that will be returned is a 0 and not a real count. Logic: Count(field) will return a single NULL for all field values that  are null and ISNULL will set that to 0, returning a 0.

Answer (score 17):

You want to put the `ISNULL` inside of the `COUNT` function, not outside:

Not GOOD: `ISNULL(COUNT(field), 0)`

GOOD: `COUNT(ISNULL(field, 0))`

Comment: This is wrong. `count(ISNULL(field, 0))` will be equivalent to `count(*)`, as the value that is being counted can no longer ever be `NULL`.

Comment: @hvd it's not wrong, the value is only 0 when field is null.

Comment: @GovindRai No, it really is wrong. If you believe you can come up with a counterexample, an example where `COUNT(ISNULL(field, 0))` is different from `COUNT(*)`, please do so, [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) makes it easy to share such a counterexample. But you won't be able to. Since `COUNT` counts the non-null values even if they are zero, and `ISNULL(field, 0)` is always non-null value, `COUNT(ISNULL(field, 0))` counts rows. That's what `COUNT(*)` is for and not what the OP here was after.

Comment: @hvd You're correct. My answer was based on a `group by` query in a different context from what the OP was after. In my case, `ISNULL(COUNT(field), 0)` would return a count of 0 for all NULL values which was incorrect since there were multiple null values whereas `COUNT(ISNULL(field),0)` would return the correct count for the total # of NULL values. But again, two totally different scenarios.

Comment: Got it to work. Here you go! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee0546/2 Upvoted your comment lol

Comment: Even all record values were null this return 1 ! It's not acceptable in most Scenario.

Comment: Can also be used in SUM function as  SUM(ISNULL(field, 0)) to resolve problem,
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting this error; I just put a `WHERE` clause for the field which was used within `count` clause. it solved the issue. Note: if null value exist, check whether its critical for the report, as its excluded in the count.

Old query:

```
select city, Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count 
from Emp_DB
group by city
```

New query:

```
select city, Count(Emp_ID) as Emp_Count 
from Emp_DB
where Emp_ID is not null
group by city
```

Answer (score -3):

If any Null value exists inside aggregate function you will face this issue. 
Instead of below code

```
 SELECT Count(closed)
  FROM   ticket
  WHERE  assigned_to = c.user_id
  AND closed IS NULL
```

use like

```
SELECT Count(ISNULL(closed, 0))
  FROM   ticket
  WHERE  assigned_to = c.user_id
  AND closed IS NULL
```