# Why warn about NULLs in COUNT(col)?

Tags: sql-server, warnings, ansi-sql

This is a bit of a philosophical question, I guess...

Say I execute this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT mygroup, COUNT(mycolumn)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mygroup
```

The counted column contains NULLs and the ANSI_WARNINGS option is ON, so I get:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
> operation.

I understand what this means. And there are lots of ways to 'fix' this warning. But... **why is it complaining in the first place?**

Skipping any NULLs is **all `COUNT(mycolumn)` does!** If I wanted to count *all* rows, including NULLs for this column, I would have used `COUNT(*)`. Isn't it clear that it's my *intention* to skip NULLs?

I guess the ANSI standard demands this warning, even in this obvious case. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

The warning only appears when an actual null is present in the aggregate resultset.  I believe it is there to remind you that nulls will not be counted and to warn you should you come across data consistency issues because a null appears where you did not expect.

Comment: I **expect** NULLs, or I would have used `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: I understand that you expect nulls, but remember ansi_warnings is enabled by default.  With this enabled, you will get warnings.  Also just because you know the difference between count(column) and count(*) there are people out there who do not understand the difference.  It is beneficial to these people to see a warning that there could be data inconsistencies or inaccurate aggregations. If you do not want this setting, you can run "set ansi_warnings off".

Comment: `ANSI_WARNINGS` are fine for `MIN`, `MAX`, etc. But for `COUNT` it's confusing IMHO.