# Getting warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, settings

I have this schema

```
create table t(id int, d date) 

insert into t (id, d) values (1, getdate()), 
                             (2, NULL)
```

When doing

```
declare @mindate date    
select @mindate = min(d) from t
```

I get the warning

> Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Why and what can I do about it?

Comment: try adding `where d is not null`

Comment: I'm getting the same warning. I don't mind the warning in and of itself, but, I need the stored procedure to be run by the SQL Agent, and when I do that, the warning causes the Agent job to fail.

Comment: @Richie It doesn't make SQL Agent jobs fail. It will appear in the output visible in the job history, which you may be looking at when the job fails for some other reason so assume is the cause

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Mostly you should do nothing about it.

- It is possible to disable the warning by setting `ansi_warnings` off but this has [other effects, e.g. on how division by zero is handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and can cause failures when your queries use features like indexed views, computed columns or XML methods.
- In some limited cases you can rewrite the aggregate to avoid it. e.g. `COUNT(nullable_column)` can be rewritten as `SUM(CASE WHEN nullable_column IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` but this isn't always possible to do straightforwardly without changing the semantics.

It's just an informational message [required in the SQL standard](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/meaning-of-set-in-error-message-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-o/18454#18454). Apart from adding unwanted noise to the messages stream it has no ill effects (other than meaning that SQL Server can't just bypass reading `NULL` rows, which can have [an overhead](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40496701-scalargbaggtotop-transformation-with-max-nullable) but disabling the warning doesn't give better execution plans in this respect)

The reason for returning this message is that throughout most operations in SQL nulls propagate.

`SELECT NULL + 3 + 7` returns `NULL` (regarding `NULL` as an unknown quantity this makes sense as `? + 3 + 7` is also unknown)

but

```
SELECT SUM(N)
FROM   (VALUES (NULL),
               (3),
               (7)) V(N)
```

Returns `10` and the warning that nulls were ignored.

However these are **exactly the semantics you want** for typical aggregation queries. Otherwise the presence of a single `NULL` would mean aggregations on that column over all rows would always end up yielding `NULL` which is not very useful.

**Which is the heaviest cake below?** ([Image Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/8514720@N04/6862029495/), [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/) image altered (cropped and annotated) by me)

[image]

After the third cake was weighed the scales broke and so no information is available about the fourth but it was still possible to measure the circumference.

```
+--------+--------+---------------+
| CakeId | Weight | Circumference |
+--------+--------+---------------+
|      1 | 50     | 12.0          |
|      2 | 80     | 14.2          |
|      3 | 70     | 13.7          |
|      4 | NULL   | 13.4          |
+--------+--------+---------------+
```

The query

```
SELECT MAX(Weight)        AS MaxWeight,
       AVG(Circumference) AS AvgCircumference
FROM   Cakes
```

Returns

```
+-----------+------------------+
| MaxWeight | AvgCircumference |
+-----------+------------------+
|        80 |          13.325  |
+-----------+------------------+
```

even though technically it is not possible to say with certainty that 80 was the weight of the heaviest cake (as the unknown number may be larger) the results above are generally more useful than simply returning unknown.

```
+-----------+------------------+
| MaxWeight | AvgCircumference |
+-----------+------------------+
|         ? |          13.325  |
+-----------+------------------+
```

So likely you want NULLs to be ignored, and the warning just alerts you to the fact that this is happening.

Comment: This properly explains the issue and allows me to happily continue ignoring the warning as that is exactly what I expected to happen.

Comment: Even though I've been irritated at null propagation on multiple occasions I guess I never really questioned the reasoning behind it. Any answer that can make me go "oohhhhh" or involves biscuits has got my vote.

Comment: I've probably googled this error a couple of times, but this was by far the best explanation of the issue, as well as why its there, and when it matters. Thank you!

Comment: This explain the "eliminated by an aggregate function", but doesn't explain the "other SET function". Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: Found by myself, the reply for who whant to know it. SET operations are not the SET word for an update (as I thought), but UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT operators

Answer (score 4):

@juergen provided two good answers:

- Suppress the warning using `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`
- Assuming you want to include NULL values and treat them as (say) use `select @mindate = min(isnull(d, cast(0 as datetime))) from t`

However if you want to ignore rows where the d column is null and not concern yourself with the `ANSI_WARNINGS` option then you can do this by excluding all rows where d is set to null as so:

```
select @mindate = min(d) from t where (d IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Your option 1 has other side effects. Your option 3 only works if that's the single aggregated column. For `select min(d1), min(d2) ` there is no where clause that can be used to do this. Why do you care about this message? It is just informational.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  My first two options were just summarising juergen's previous answers in order to form a platform on which to introduce my option (3?).  Yes, my suggestion only works if it is the only aggregated (min, max, avg, sum etc.) column being selected which is as the OP presented the question.  The message might only be informational but when I see them they always make me question the query which breaks my concentration at the job at hand.

Answer (score 2):

What should `min()` return in your case as lowest value of `d`?

The error informs you that the `min()` function did not take records into account that are `null`.

So if it should ignore the `NULL` values and return the lowest **existing** date then you can ignore this warning.

If you also like to suppress warnings for this single statement then you can do it like this

```
set ansi_warnings off
select @mindate = min(d) from t
set ansi_warnings on
```

If you want `NULL` values taken into account by using a default value for them then you can set a default date value like this

```
select @mindate = min(isnull(d, cast(0 as datetime)))
from t
```

Comment: Your suggested "fix" will return incorrect results. It will indicate that the earliest date was `1900-01-01` (except if there happens to be  date earlier than that in the data)

Comment: What will happen if `d` has these two values like '1/1/2001' and '1/1/2012'. This will return '1/1/1900' as min value? So if do `select * from table where date>@mindate` this will cause trouble

Answer (score 2):

I think you can ignore this warning in the case since you using the `MIN` function.

***"Except for COUNT, aggregate functions ignore null values"***

Please refer [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make aggregates consider `null` values and treat the result as `null` you can use:

```
SELECT IIF(COUNT(N) != COUNT(*), NULL, SUM(N)) as [Sum]
FROM   (VALUES (NULL),
               (3),
               (7)) V(N)
```

This returns `null` if not all values are given.