# Warning: Null value is eliminated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table (see image) and the Columns Number of accidents and Numberof Preventable accidents should display data, however they come up as all NULL. How do I fix it? Thank you

[image]

Comment: You sure that's where it's throwing the warning? Have you separated that part of the code off into another SSMS window? Regardless if you want to get rid of the warning you can `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF GO` But i'm pretty sure this isn't where your warning is coming from.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN is effectively INNER because the WHERE predicate requires left joined table column to be not NULL. Probably that is the problem. The warning is OK see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719436/getting-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation

Comment: What is the next piece of code for the final select?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is because you are doing aggregation using null values

Let me explain with an example as below:

```
create TABLE #test (ID INT, Qty INT, Price MONEY)
INSERT INTO #test (ID, Qty, Price) SELECT 1, 25, 100
INSERT INTO #test (ID, Qty, Price) SELECT 2, NULL, 200
INSERT INTO #test (ID, Qty, Price) SELECT 3, 5, NULL

SELECT SUM(Qty)  FROM #test WHERE ID IN (1,3)
-- no warning
--Because qty in id 1,3 is not null

SELECT SUM(Price) FROM #test WHERE ID IN (1,3)
-- Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
-- Because price 100 is added with NULL

SELECT AVG(Qty)  FROM #test WHERE ID IN (1,2)
-- Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
-- Because qty is null + 25 to get average
```

Comment: But the OP is using ISNULL on all aggregations.... hence the problem shouldn't be on the snippet shown.