# Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation on Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I'm receiving this error doing an UPDATE?

for example:

```
UPDATE dbo.[EmployeeManager]  SET [ManagerId] = NULL WHERE [EmployeeId] = 1
```

I understand applying aggregate functions and calculations but this? I don't get it.

Comment: I believe because you already have some records null in ManagerId column

Comment: Instead of providing an example, please provide an ACTUAL query where you are seeing this message

Comment: do you have multiple records in the table some of which were NULL to start with? as such null didn't get set to null as it was already null? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719436/getting-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation

Comment: that's my ACTUALquery and yes, the ManagerId is already NULL and I'm updating it again

Comment: Do you have triggers?

Comment: Include in the where `and [ManagerID] is not null`. warning goes away.  The engine is just warning you that you're attempting to a set a value to null ant it is already. Rather than waste the IO time, it's choosing to ignore the update as it is redundant; and perhaps in error of what you're trying to accomplish https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/meaning-of-set-in-error-message-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-o

Comment: yes, nothing to do with that column, but I believe you are right