# SQL COUNT returns "Null value eliminated" error on left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit of code that looks roughly like this:

```
DECLARE @Test int, @LookupVal varchar(50) = 'test'
SELECT @Test = COUNT(M.MembershipID)
FROM dbo.Users U WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN dbo.UserMemberships M WITH (NOLOCK) ON M.UserID = U.UserID
AND M.MembershipID = @LookupVal
SELECT @Test
```

This works fine when the lookup returns multiple rows; the second SELECT returns the number of rows. If there are no MembershipIDs with value 'test' it correctly shows 0, but the system log also show the error message "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

I know I could disable this with SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF. However, I am convinced this must be some setting I (or a coworker) have accidentally changed on our instance of SQL Server. I have written lots of statements in this format throughout a large code base, and I have never before seen this error until today. I want to know what setting might have changed, so I can switch that back.

Another change that fixes it is removing the LEFT; as a regular JOIN this correctly returns the value 0 with no other errors. Also if I simply SELECT COUNT(M.MembershipID) without putting it into the @Test variable, then it simply displays 0 and no error. It is only on a LEFT JOIN with the variable that the error occurs.

NOTE: I am not simply asking about this message, or looking for a way to disable it in this specific case. I want to know why it has suddenly started happening in an old bit of code, specifically caused by the combination of a left join and selecting into a variable.

Comment: It's not an error, it's pure information. (Some rows where M.MembershipID is null weren't counted.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719436/getting-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation)

Comment: You might also take a peek here before you continue using NOLOCK everywhere. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You could just change this to an inner join since you are only wanting a count of UserMemberships. :)

Answer (score 0):

Q: "I want to know what setting might have changed"

If there was a SQL Server setting that changed (which is now causing the "NULL value is eliminated" warning to be issued when it wasn't before...)

I think you answered you own question.

Maybe the `ANSI_WARNINGS` database option that was enabled. Or possibly the `ANSI_DEFAULTS` database option.

These database options are default values, they aren't enforced in the database. These can be overridden and ignored by the client connection to the database. So its also possible that the connection string was changed.

---

I think this may all be barking up the wrong tree, about a setting change.

There are a variety of simple query changes will eliminate the warning, and at the same time, make the intent of the query more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming your query output the intended results

DECLARE @Test int, @LookupVal varchar(50) = 'test' 
SELECT @Test = COUNT(M.MembershipID)  
FROM  dbo.UserMemberships M WITH (NOLOCK)  
LEFT JOIN dbo.Users U WITH (NOLOCK) ON M.UserID = U.UserID  
WHERE M.MembershipID = @LookupVal 
SELECT @Test
```

OR

```
If you want to keep the same format of the query

SELECT @Test = COUNT(ISNULL(M.MembershipID,''))
FROM dbo.Users U WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN dbo.UserMemberships M WITH (NOLOCK) ON M.UserID = U.UserID
AND M.MembershipID = @LookupVal
```