# Suppress warnings in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a very similar problem to [Getting warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719436/getting-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/18719852#18719852). Basically I have a warning message that is popping up, in this case a null value being eliminated in an aggregate function. There are also a few other warning messages that pop up that are irrelevant to me and I would like to make it were warning messages don't pop up when running this set of SQL statements.

One of the options mentioned in the linked question is to use "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;". I also use a similar option in MS-Access vba. What is the equivalent, if any, for Sybase? I am running a series of queries using Sybase's Interactive SQL window.

Worst case scenario I will restructure the query to eliminate nulls from the aggregate function but I'd prefer to just turn off these warning messages.

Comment: It's probably worth stating which Sybase production specifically as there are multiple products available each with differing options i.e. ASE, IQ, Anywhere, ADS and also the precise error message.

Comment: Not even sure exactly. The software I use is called Sybase Central and the connection method with the database uses "SQL Anywhere 16". Other than that, I don't know any of the specifics or jargon. I'm even vague aware that t-SQL is a thing with sybase, I think, and I have no idea if that is what the interactive SQL window is using or not. However I did find one solution yesterday so I'm going to post that soon as well. Edit: Looking at the webpage I used to find the answer, I'm guessing SAP and T-SQL are being used?

Comment: It sounds like you're using SAP SQL Anywhere then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one way of doing this is to use `set ansinull off;` For me this stopped the message from popping up and hasn't changed any of the results as far as I can tell.

This setting only affects that session in the interactive SQL. If you close it and open a new one, the null warning messages will start popping up again so this isn't making a permanent change to the database.

http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/set-tsql-statement.html

Comment: I am tentatively accepting this answer. If anyone can post an answer with a way to turn off, preferably temporarily, all warning messages using a similar method I will accept it as the answer.