# T-SQL How to Match Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables, package table and product table. In my case, the package contains multiple products. We need to recognize multiple products whether they can match a package which is already in package records. Some scripts are below.

```
DECLARE @tblPackage TABLE(
    PackageID   int,
    ProductID   int
)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4305)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4986)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(437, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(437, 4305)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(442, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(442, 4335)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(445, 4305)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(445, 4335)
```

[image]

```
DECLARE @tblProduct TABLE(
    ProductID   int
)

INSERT INTO @tblProduct VALUES(4305) 
INSERT INTO @tblProduct VALUES(4313)
```

[image]

We have two product 4305 and 4313, then I need to retrieve the matched package record 437. Only the exactly matched one can be return, so package 436 is not the right one. It's not easy to make a multiple rows query clause. please someone can have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: so in other words, if one product is contained in more than one package then retrieve the row that has the product with the higher PackageID?

Comment: I think you are trying to find the package that contains exactly this set of products?

Comment: Why not 436? It contains both your products?

Comment: can you explain the logic around why 437 is returned and not other rows, or is that simply a parameter that you want to retrieve all  products for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  [***SQLFIDDLE DEMO***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb8e1/16)

```
Declare @cnt Int
Select @cnt = count(distinct ProductID) from tblProduct 

SELECT B.packageid 
FROM   (SELECT packageid 
        FROM   tblpackage 
        GROUP  BY packageid 
        HAVING Count(productid) = @cnt) A 
       JOIN tblpackage B 
         ON a.packageid = b.packageid 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM tblproduct c WHERE c.productid = b.productid) 
GROUP  BY B.packageid 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT B.productid) = @cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  I would approach it using aggregation and `having`:

```
select p.PackageID
from @tblPackage p left join
     @tblProduct pr
     on p.ProductId = pr.ProductId
group by p.PackageId
having count(*) = count(pr.ProductId) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from @tblProduct);
```

The `left join` keeps all products for each package.  The first condition in the `having` clause says that all these products match what is in the product table.  The second says that all the products are actually there.

Note that if you have duplicates in either table, then you'll need to use `count(distinct)` in one or more places.  Your sample data suggests that this is not an issue.

Comment: @Linoff, thanks, the result set is correct. But there is an warning message: Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. Although I changed the column definition to NOT NULL. The warning message still exsit.

Comment: @BesLey . . . It is not actually important.  Here is more of an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384292/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation-in-aqua.

Comment: OK, There is about millions package record in future. I am not sure which query will have better performance with you and [NoDisplayName], although two solution both work well now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
;WITH MatchingRows
AS
(
    SELECT P1.PackageID, P1.ProductID 
    FROM @tblPackage P1
    INNER JOIN @tblProduct P2
        ON P1.ProductID = P2.ProductID
)
SELECT DISTINCT P1.PackageID
FROM @tblPackage P1
INNER JOIN @tblProduct P2
    ON P1.ProductID = P2.ProductID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblPackage P3 WHERE P3.PackageID = P1.PackageID) /* How may products are in this package */
    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MatchingRows WHERE MatchingRows.PackageID = P1.PackageID) /* how many matching rows in this package - are they the same*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful..

```
DECLARE @tblPackage TABLE(
    PackageID   int,
    ProductID   int
)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4305)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(436, 4986)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(437, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(437, 4305)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(442, 4313)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(442, 4335)

INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(445, 4305)
INSERT INTO @tblPackage VALUES(445, 4335)

DECLARE @tblProduct TABLE(
    ProductID   int
)

INSERT INTO @tblProduct VALUES(4305) 
INSERT INTO @tblProduct VALUES(4313)

SELECT A.PackageID FROM
    (SELECT PackageID,
           CombinedProductID = 
            (
                SELECT
                    CAST(t2.ProductID AS VARCHAR(100))
                FROM @tblPackage t2
                WHERE
                    t2.PackageID = t1.PackageID
                GROUP BY t2.ProductID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
            )
    FROM @tblPackage t1
    GROUP BY t1.PackageID) AS A
INNER JOIN     
    (SELECT (SELECT ProductID 
         FROM @tblProduct 
         ORDER BY ProductID  
         FOR XML PATH (''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)') 
     AS CombinedProductID) AS B

ON A.CombinedProductID = B.CombinedProductID
```