# suppress warnings in file export from sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Googled a bit but could not find anything useful. Can someone please be so kind and tell me how to suppress messages like this:

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation

in the file export in sql server management studio? Thanks.

Comment: [`SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-warnings-transact-sql) will suppress this, but it has other consequences (operations on indexed computed columns and views may fail to work). The best option going forward would be to actually find and fix the queries doing this by adding appropriate `ISNULL` clauses.

Comment: How exactly are you exporting the data from SSMS? I wouldn't expect the warning message to be included with the data.

Comment: results to file @DanGuzman

Comment: thanks @JeroenMostert that will do - might be worth composing answer? Thanks.

Comment: Btw can this be set as a default (like tab separated) instead of using code SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

Comment: Tools -> Options..., Query Execution -> SQL Server -> ANSI. And now that you know how, *don't actually do it* unless your job is literally just saving results to files. One day something will fail because you changed a setting SQL Server really wants to have `ON` to `OFF`, and you'll forget why.

Comment: Ok makes sense - will use code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384292/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation-in-aqua