# How to include count of NULL values in a temp table without changing the NULL data to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with these values

```
create table LoanExample (
        LoanId int,
        ConstraintId int,
        BorrowerName varchar(128));

    insert into LoanExample values (1, null, 'Jack')
    insert into LoanExample values (1, 33, 'July')
    insert into LoanExample values (2, 78, 'Mike')
    insert into LoanExample values (2, 72, 'Wayne')
    insert into LoanExample values (3, null, 'David')
    insert into LoanExample values (3, 79, 'Chris')
    insert into LoanExample values (4, null, 'Finn')
    insert into LoanExample values (4, null, 'James')
```

I want to count the constraints of each LoanId even if its value is `null`and add it into a temp table.

I tried this

```
    select 
        LoanId,
        Constraints_Count = count(ConstraintId)
    into #Test
    from LoanExample
    group by LoanId
```

But this query ignores all the null values in the count function and gives me a warning message "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."
!

I expected `Constraints_Count` of each LoanId to be '2' but for the LoanId which has a `ConstraintId` as null has a reduced value in `Constraints_Count`.

So, for LoanId 1 and 3 I get `Constraints_Count` as '1' but I expect '2' and for LoanId 4, I get `Constraints_Count` as '0' but I expect '2'.

I suppose I can use `ROW_NUMBER()` but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation in Aqua Data Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384292/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation-in-aqua)

Comment: Why not just COUNT(*) in your current query?

Comment: Is there a possibility of duplicate constraints that you wouldn't want to count, e.g. `42`, `null`, `42`, `666` would be a count of `3` rather than `4`? Otherwise it appears that a simple `Count( * )` will, as previously suggested, suffice.

Comment: @HABO In that case do I need to add a `distinct` somewhere?

Comment: It seems that you don't want `distinct`, you want a count of all of the rows for each value of `LoanId` regardless of the value of `ConstraintId`. Naming the column `Constraints_Count` is a red herring because it is really `LoanIdCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS, you could convert null to 0.

SQL Server:

```
select 
        LoanId,
        Constraints_Count = count(isnull(ConstraintId,0))
    into #Test
    from LoanExample
    group by LoanId
```

Oracle:

```
select 
        LoanId,
        Constraints_Count = count(nvl(ConstraintId,0))
    into #Test
    from LoanExample
    group by LoanId
```

Other:

```
select 
        LoanId,
        Constraints_Count = count(case when ConstraintId is null then 0 else ConstraintId end))
    into #Test
    from LoanExample
    group by LoanId
```

Comment: This is just not the best solution.

Comment: I might agree if the question was "count the records in the table".  But it was specifically "count the records in the constraintid field without losing the nulls".  Granted the result is the same, but my answer could be used for other people with similar questions (like if they want to count the unique records including the nulls).

Answer (score 3):

simply use count(*) or sum(1):

```
select 
    LoanId,
    Constraints_Count = count(*)
into #Test
from LoanExample
group by LoanId
```

Or

```
select 
    LoanId,
    Constraints_Count = sum(1)
into #Test
from LoanExample
group by LoanId
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: I might agree if the question was "count the records in the table".  But it was specifically "count the records in the constraintid field without losing the nulls".  Granted the result is the same, but my answer could be used for other people with similar questions (like if they want to count the unique records including the nulls).

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [`coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which will convert null values to a valid integer value:

```
Constraints_Count = count(coalesce(ConstraintId,1))
```

In your case the value 1 I used is irrelevant. It could be any other integer value.

Answer (score 0):

count() work  on null value so you could  try using a case for invert the null values

```
select 
    LoanId,
    count(case when ConstraintId is null then 1 else null)  Constraints_Count
from LoanExample
group by LoanId
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using case when

```
    select 
    LoanId,
    Constraints_Count = sum(case when ConstraintId is null then 1 else 1 end)
into #Test
from LoanExample
group by LoanId
```