# SET ANSI _WARNINGS OFF is not working in my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I am executing a stored procedure,I'm getting Warning message

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I am trying to remove the warning message by adding `'SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF'` before starting the procedure.But still i'm getting the warning message and the recompiled procedure not taking the `'ANSI_WARNINGS OFF'` command. My procedure is having lot of calculations and lot of nested procedures also. It's hard to find out which calculation causing error.

Comment: Do not set ansi_warnings off. Instead, try to fix the problem.

Comment: **similar post:**
============= [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384292/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation-in-aqua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384292/warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation-in-aqua)

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some code? In general, the issue is that your are using `count(col)` or `sum(col)` or `max(col)` etc., *without* a `WHERE col IS NOT NULL`

I know you said it's hard to find out what's causing the error, but it's best to find it since the NULL values can be causing invalid results: averages, for example would be wrong, or sums where NULL might need to be represented by 0. In such cases, you might want to use `ISNULL(col, 0)` or something similar. It's hard to tell without knowing your data or code.