# In Azure synapse SQL POOL getting Setting AnsiWarnings to 'OFF' is not supported how to turn it off then

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

In Azure synapse SQL POOL I am getting Setting AnsiWarnings to 'OFF' is not supported warning message  how to turn it off then.
While executing my store procedure I am getting "Null value is Eliminated by an Aggregate or Other SET Operation" this error that is why I wanted to turn off so that it can execute for those null values as well.

Any solution Will help
Thank you

Comment: _"this error that is why I wanted to turn off so that it can execute for those null values as well."_ - I have a much better idea: **fix the underlying bug in your query** instead of sweeping errors under the rug. [All you need to do is filter-out `NULL` arguments to those functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11384292/159145).

Comment: Post the query generating this warning and we can help remove it. It's as simple as using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in the right place

Answer (score 0):

This

> null value is Eliminated by an Aggregate or Other SET Operation

Is not a error, it's only a warning.  It doesn't stop the results from being sent to the client.

If a client treats this as an error, that's a bug.  You can work around it as mentioned in the other comments.